# Android app to listen for sound and record volume, using Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, audio, cordova

I'm trying to write an app that will listen for sound over a phone/tablet's microphone. I think capturing sound is not too hard, I've found some code [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media).

I was wondering how I would go about associating a volume level? Ideally I'd like to convert the sound level into decibels, but any arbitrary scale would do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just used the Java SDK to do this, and then when I converted the app to iOS I rewrote it in objective-c.

On Android you can import the following libraries:

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
```

And then make some calls like this to see the amplitude of the audio recording:

```
int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,minSize);

short[] buffer = new short[minSize];
ar.startRecording();
while(1){
    ar.read(buffer, 0, val*minSize);        
    average_buffer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++){
            average_buffer += (int) Math.sqrt((float)buffer[i]*buffer[i]);
    }
    Log.i("NOISE LEVEL", Integer.toString(average_buffer);
}
```